# I want to delete every message until 10 seconds ago

Tags: discord, discord.py, purge

Title mostly says it, i have tried various ways, i tried making a variable = 1 and appen every message in a list, then after 10 seconds say that list = [], I got help from the pyhton discord server but it didn't work at the end, then i saw on the docs that there is  way to delete messages after a certain date but I don't know how to set it to 10 seconds ago so I'm asking if anyone has any idea on how to do it, my code:

```
@commands.cooldown(rate=1,per=25,type=commands.BucketType.user)
async def king_crimson(ctx):
    kingcrimson = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=817441099173199923)
    if kingcrimson in ctx.author.roles:
        kc_list = []
        kc_ability = []
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        kc_embed = discord.Embed(title="King Crimson activated!", colour=discord.Colour(0xb90d0d))
        await ctx.author.send(embed=kc_embed)
        kc_ability = 1
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        kc_ability = 0
        kc_embed2 = discord.Embed(title="Time has skipped!", colour=discord.Colour(0xb90d0d))
        await ctx.author.send(embed=kc_embed2)
        await ctx.channel.purge(after=10)
```

basically when the command is triggered it will wait 10 seconds and then delete every message in those 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

When the command is called, store the current time as a datetime object:

```py
import datetime

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

await asyncio.sleep(10)

now = datetime.datetime.now()
await ctx.channel.purge(before=now, after=start_time, bulk=True)
```

You should also specify `bulk=True` so all the messages are deleted at once. You may also want to set a check so that the bots messages aren't deleted. You can find more information about the purge command [**here**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=purge#discord.TextChannel.purge).